# opensense traffic not out and back in

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, pfsense

I have setup opensense with vitual ips, nat-one to one forwarding rules. Able to communicate externally. Can also communicate internally as well as access directly from outside.
Problem is when it tries accessing a site from a virtual machine that is hosted behind the firewall on a different virtual machine. as the traffic tries going out but when traffic tries combing back in it isblocked by some firewall rule.
Have added pass firewall rules for all source and destination networks with default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

under firewall->settings->advanced.
enabling following rules:
- Reflection for 1:1
- Automatic outbound NAT for Reflection
fixed the issue.